# How do I configure Apache to use UPnP?

Tags: webserver, port-forwarding, upnp

In home networks based on modern routers supporting UPnP, torrent clients just work: they ask the UPnP gateway to open a port for them when needed.

Yet, every guide I have seen about setting up a web server includes steps which manually enable port forwarding on the router. Why aren't web servers using UPnP for this purpose? Is there a technical limitation preventing them from doing so?

To make the question less open-ended, how do I configure Apache to use UPnP?

Comment: For things like torrent you tell the world where to connect to, and this is typically valid for a few hours. A local web server could use UPnP, but this doesn't tell the world how to connect. The effort in telling the world dwarfs the effort of setting up port forwarding. Of course some people don't allow UPnP in the first place on their routers.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask specifies: _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page._ Therefore, please tell us what your use case is.

Comment: "when needed." - webservers need this all the time, on one particular port. So it's enough to do it once. Also, web servers usually run in very different environments compared to your home with a modem routers supporting UPnP. But nothing keeps you from configuring your web server to use UPnP when it gets started; that's a simple wrapper script under Linux.

Comment: @K7AAY My use case is to set up a web server in a manner that doesn't depend on a particular provider, so that if I post a guide on the Internet, other people can follow it without getting stuck at "do what your router documentation tells about opening a port".